# How to set row order of a dataframe that has a long format?

Tags: python, pandas

*Full code sample below*

Let's take the [iris dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) as an example. The length of the dataframe is `150` and , the column `species` contain the three unique values  `['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']`. And they appear in the dataframe column in the same order as that list. But how do I specify that order?

The original order can be found using:

```
# In:
df['species'].unique()

# Out:
# array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], dtype=object)
```

A reverse alphabetical order is easily applied like this:

```
# In:
df_alpha = df.sort_values(by='species', ascending=False)
df_alpha.unique()

# Out:
array(['virginica', 'versicolor', 'setosa'], dtype=object)
```

But how can I specify the order to be `['virginica', 'setosa', 'versicolor']`?

---

**Code and reproducible data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
df_alpha = df.sort_values(by='species', ascending=False)
df_alpha.tail()
```

**Structure of the dataframe:**

```
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species  species_id
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa         1
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa         1
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa         1
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa         1
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa         1
.
.
.

145           6.7          3.0           5.2        2.3  virginica     3   
146           6.3          2.5           5.0        1.9  virginica     3
147           6.5          3.0           5.2        2.0  virginica     3
148           6.2          3.4           5.4        2.3  virginica     3
149           5.9          3.0           5.1        1.8  virginica     3
```

Comment: I think you need `ordered categorical`s

Comment: @jezrael I tried the different approaches to the linked question, but I could not get them to work. Any further suggestions on how to get it to work on this dataset? I think the data sample in the linked question is too limited.

Comment: so `cats = ['virginica', 'setosa', 'versicolor']
df['species'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['species'], ordered=True, categories=cats)
df_alpha = df.sort_values('species')` not working for you?

Comment: @jezrael Now it did! I must have messed up something along the way. Thank you so much for your help!